# Refreshing fragment in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 3 fragments A, B, C in a view pager. I am making a change in fragment B which should refresh the list adapter in fragment A. What I tried so far :

Implemented view pager on page change listener and wrote the code to refresh the view pager adapter. It works.but the scrolling lags now. Code I tried:

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener (new OnPageChangeListener (){
 @Override
 public void onPageSelected (int pos){
 if (pos==0)
 mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged ();}
```

Adapter code:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition (Object obj){
return POSITION_NONE;}
```

Any suggestions on how to reduce the lag or any other method to refresh the fragment?

P.S. I tried implementing interface also but getActivity in frgament was returning me null.

Comment: This is not a good way of using ViewPager. Could you please explain why you are trying to do it? There must be better way of handling this.

Comment: I need to refresh the list adapter in fragment A when I make a change in fragment B. Any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Call your adapters notifyDataSetChanged method will refresh the list.

Comment: Yup do what @KartihkrajDuraisamy said. But you need to inform your fragment that there is a need to call the notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter. Two ways you can do it. Use listener interface or use BroadcastReveiver.

Comment: @Varundroid: Communication should be there between those to do so. You are right...

Comment: Can you please give an example code? I need to call the view pager adapter s notifydatasetchanged or fragment A adapter s .And if you are talking about fragment A adapter notifydatasetchanged, I have tried that using interface but it resulted in null pointer in getActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener (new OnPageChangeListener ()
       {
         @Override
         public void onPageSelected (int pos){
         if (pos==1)
         mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged ();
        }
```